# Parsing user data into &body attribute of mailto form

Tags: javascript, forms, innerhtml, mailto

I have this script:

```
function calculate(){

passworda = document.password1.user1.value.toLowerCase()
passwordb = document.password1.pass1.value.toLowerCase()

var user = 1
var pass = 1

for(d=0;d<passwordb.length;d++) {
pass*= passwordb.charCodeAt(d);
}
for(e=0;e< passworda.length; e++) {
user *= passworda.charCodeAt(e);
    }
      document.password1.outputuser1.value = user;
      document.password1.outputpass1.value = pass;
}
```

and this form:

```
<form name="password1" enctype="text/plain" method="get" action="mailto:myemail@mydomain.com?subject=Register&body=A new user has registered with your form. Their username is ' +outputuser1+ ' and their password is ' +outputpass1+ '">
Username:<input type="text" name="user1" />
Password:<input type="password" name="pass1" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="calculate()" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

What I want to do is when a user fills out this form and hits submit, it emails me with their encrypted username and password, replacing

`&body=A new user has registered with your form. Their username is ' +outputuser1+ ' and their password is ' +outputpass1+ '"`

with

`&body=A new user has registered with your form. Their user name is JOHNSMITH and their password is 123456"`

when the form gets submitted. I'm not getting any javascript errors, but when the email window opens, the body and subject are blank.

Can anyone help get this working please? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms with `mailto:` uris are [too poorly supported](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) for use on the WWW.

If you want to collect data with a form then you **need** to use an HTTP(S) URI as the action, and process submitted data on the server.

Comment: While I am familiar with the disadvantages and lack of support for `mailto` , it is necessary in this secnario. Is there any workaround at all?